# Error in Populating list in select box

Tags: java, struts2

I am able to get the list from my database(I am using ORM ie Hibernate).

List type is of my Bean class.

But the problem that I am facing is :

1. The list populated in SELECT BOX is having Object. Not the values.

Required is that it should populate names.

Action Class:

```java
package com.action;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.ing.aosh.service.AoshService;
import com.ing.aosh.vo.EscRprtNameVO;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class FileUploadAction extends ActionSupport  implements SessionAware{

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FileUploadAction.class.getName());
    private Map session;
    private String slectList;
    EscRprtNameVO escNameRprtVo = new EscRprtNameVO();
     private File report;
        private String reportContentType;
        private String reportFileName;  
      private List escRprtNameList = new ArrayList(); 

    @Autowired
    AoshService aoshService;

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        escRprtNameList = aoshService.getEscRprtNmNid();
        System.out.println("escRprtNameList 2==" + ((EscRprtNameVO) escRprtNameList.get(2)).getEscRprtName());
        System.out.println("escRprtNameList 4==" + ((EscRprtNameVO) escRprtNameList.get(4)).getEscRprtName());
        session.put("ESCRPTDETAILS", escRprtNameList);
        return "success";
    }

        public AoshService getAoshService() {
            return aoshService;
        }

        public void setAoshService(AoshService aoshService) {
            this.aoshService = aoshService;
        }

        public void setSession(Map session) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            this.session = session;

        }

        public EscRprtNameVO getEscNameRprtVo() {
            return escNameRprtVo;
        }

        public void setEscNameRprtVo(EscRprtNameVO escNameRprtVo) {
            this.escNameRprtVo = escNameRprtVo;
        }

        public String getSlectList() {
            return slectList;
        }

        public void setSlectList(String slectList) {
            this.slectList = slectList;
        }

        public List getEscRprtNameList() {
            return escRprtNameList;
        }

        public void setEscRprtNameList(List escRprtNameList) {
            this.escRprtNameList = escRprtNameList;
        }
}
```

JSP PAGE:

```
  <s:set name="esclatnRprtName" value="#session.ESCRPTDETAILS"></s:set>
  <td align="left">
     <s:if test="#esclatnRprtName != null">      
        <s:select list="esclatnRprtName" name="slectList"/>
     </s:if>
  </td>
```

for the above JSP code it is giving me select box of OBJECT VALUE

Modified JSP PAGE

```jsp
   <s:set name="esclatnRprtName" value="#session.ESCRPTDETAILS"/>
   <td align="left">
      <s:if test="#esclatnRprtName != null">      
         <s:select list="esclatnRprtName" name="slectList"
                   listKey="esclatnRprtName['escNameRprtVo.escId']"
                   listValue="esclatnRprtName['escNameRprtVo.escRprtName']"/>
      </s:if>
   </td>
```

List itself is not populating..

Request for help or suggestions

Comment: Where did you populate the select list?

Comment: The naming of your variables REALLY SUCKS. Why no vocals ? They're for free :&

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <s:select list="esclatnRprtName" name="slectList"
   listKey="escId"
   listValue="escRprtName"></s:select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the octothorpe in the `<s:select>` to the references of `esclatnRprtName` as you did in your `<s:if>` statement:

```
 <s:select list="#esclatnRprtName" name="slectList"
```

and refer directly to the listed objects in listKey and listValue:

```
 listKey="escId"
 listValue="escRprtName" />
```

When all works, you should probably:

- rename all your variables adding the vocals and making them understandable for future poor guys that will handle your code when you will be on something else;
- stop for a moment to think WHY do you need to use this complex method that involves Session to perform a simple operation like this, instead of using a simple Action variable through accessors and mutators.

Comment: `<s:set name="esclatnRprtName" value="#session.ESCRPTDETAILS"/>` is legal expression.

Comment: @AndreaLigios thanks it worked for me....  Can you please elaborate what do you mean by "adding vocals".To be very honest I didn't get you on this.. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped. By adding vocals i mean that `selectList` is more readable than `slectList`, `getEscReportNumNid` is better than `getEscRprtNmNid` etc... Imho, it's good to use `Num` instead of `Number`, but not `Nm`...

Comment: @AndreaLigios: thanks boss.. U took it in wrong way I meant 'What you replied implementing the same worked for me..' I whole heatedly accept  that you dragged me out of this.  :) M really thankful to you..